# Unable to open input kickstart file curl#37

Tags: rhel7, kickstart

Getting the below error while installing from ks.cfg
`unable to open input kickstart file curl#37  Couldn't open file /tmp/swappart`

Here am trying to include /tmp/swappart file from pre section under disks and partition section. Dont know where exactly am doing wrong.
My kickstart file looks like below,

```
install
            cdrom
            eula --agreed
            firstboot --disable
            text
            reboot

            # System
            lang en_US.UTF-8
            keyboard us

            # Network information
            network  --bootproto=static --device=ens192 --onboot=off --ipv6=auto --no-activate
            network  --hostname=localhost.localdomain

            # Authentication
            auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5
            rootpw xxxx
            %pre
            act_mem=$((`grep MemTotal: /proc/meminfo | sed ‘s/^MemTotal: *//’|sed ‘s/ .*//’` / 1024/2))
            cat > /tmp/swappart <<END
            logvol swap --fstype="swap" --name=lv_swap --vgname=sysvg --size=$act_mem
            END
            %end
            # Disk & Partitions
            bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda
            ignoredisk --only-use=sda
            bootloader --location=mbr --boot-drive=sda
            zerombr
            clearpart --all --initlabel --drives=sda
            part /boot --fstype xfs --size=1000
            part pv.01  --size=100000 --grow
            volgroup sysvg pv.01
            logvol /     --vgname=sysvg --fstype=xfs    --name=lv_root --size=20000
            logvol /var  --vgname=sysvg --fstype=xfs    --name=lv_var  --size=50000
            logvol /tmp  --vgname=sysvg --fstype=xfs    --name=lv_tmp  --size=10000
            logvol /home --vgname=sysvg --fstype=xfs    --name=lv_home --size=20000
    logvol none  --vgname=sysvg --fstype="None" --name=rpool   --size=11544 --thinpool --grow
            %include /tmp/swappart
            ######################################################
            # Packages
            %packages
            @Core
            authconfig
            yum-utils
            binutils.x86_64
            compat-libcap1.x86_64
            gcc.x86_64
            gcc-c++.x86_64
            glibc.i686
            glibc.x86_64
            glibc-devel.i686
            glibc-devel.x86_64
            ksh
            libaio.i686
            libaio.x86_64
            libaio-devel.i686
            libaio-devel.x86_64
            libgcc.i686
            libgcc.x86_64
            libstdc++.i686
            libstdc++.x86_64
            libstdc++-devel.i686
            libstdc++-devel.x86_64
            libXi.i686
            libXi.x86_64
            libXtst.i686
            libXtst.x86_64
            make.x86_64
            sysstat.x86_64
            zip
            unzip
            perl
            vim
            net-tools
            autofs
            nfs-utils
            open-vm-tools
            sos
            mlocate
            ed
            -mariadb-libs
            %end
```

TIA

Comment: It might have something to do with all the extra whitespace. You should remove that and try again.

Comment: @ Michael Hampton Thanks for the suggetsion..whitespace was the issue. After removing its working fine